# How to get columns that are referenced in another table a certain number of times? in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have two hypothetical tables

- `Country` (CountryCode, CountryName)
- `Groups` (GroupId, GroupName, CountryCode)

I know that group is a reserved word but it's just for the sake of the example

What I want to get is the countries with 3 or more groups without the use of another referential table.

I have tried the following

```
select *
from Country c
where CountryCode in (select g.CountryCode
                      from Group g
                      where g.CountryCode=c.CountryCode
                      group by g.CountryCode
                      having count(*) > 3)
```

But I get no results given I have the following data in my `Groups` table:

```
|GroupId|GroupName|CountryCode|
|   1   |  'asd'  |    USA    |
|   4   |  'fgh'  |    USA    |
|   3   |  'jkl'  |    USA    |
|   4   |  'zxc'  |    ARG    |
```

The result I want is:

```
|CountryCode| CountryName|
|    USA    |UnitedStates|
```

because there 3 groups with the `CountryCode = USA`

Comment: Try removing the where-clause within the nested select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get those country code by using **GROUP BY** and **Having** then Join the result with `Country` table, you will get your expected result.

```
select C.*
from 
(
   select g.CountryCode
   from Group g
   group by g.CountryCode
   having count(*) >= 3
) CC
INNER JOIN Country C ON C.CountryCode = CC.CountryCode
```

**UPDATE Without JOIN**

```
select C.*
from Country C
WHERE C.CountryCode IN
(
   select g.CountryCode
   from Group g
   group by g.CountryCode
   having count(*) >= 3
)
```

Comment: thanks can this be solved without an inner join? just curious

Comment: It is 3 or more, your Having clause should have `count(*) >= 3`

Comment: @LucasAraujo, Yes you can do that without inner join. check the updated part.

Comment: oooh that's why the dude in the comment told me to remove the where in the selected clause, thanks this is basically what I did but without that dumb mistake!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost true without **where clause** But Answer of @Mahedi Sabuj is better for performance

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Country c
 WHERE CountryCode IN 
                (
                  SELECT g.CountryCode
                  FROM Group g
                  GROUP BY g.CountryCode
                  HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select c.CountryCode,  c.CountryName  
FROM [Country] c
INNER JOIN [Group] g ON c.CountryCode = g.CountryCode
GROUP BY c.CountryCode,  c.CountryName 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT GroupName) >= 3
```

Comment: why count distinct groupname? Group name is not unique, what if two different groups have the same name?